# Int Overflow in Scala

Tags: scala

Why Int overflow is occured this code?

[code]

```
val randomList = List(scala.util.Random.nextInt(), scala.util.Random.nextInt(), scala.util.Random.nextInt(), scala.util.Random.nextInt())
var listSum = 0
for (value <- randomList) {
    listSum += value
    println("value = " + value)
    println("listSum = " + listSum)
    println("\n")
}
println("sum is " + listSum)
```

[Result]

value = 2078728151
listSum = 2078728151

value = -1367097617
listSum = 711630534

value = 1543963641
listSum = -2039373121

value = -1351834340
listSum = 903759835

sum is 903759835

randomList: List[Int] = List(2078728151, -1367097617, 1543963641, -1351834340)

listSum: Int = 903759835

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scala `Int` is 4 bytes long, so the greatest Integer is 2**(32-1)-1, which happens to be

```
Int.MaxValue = 2147483647
```

Any value above that is going to be `Int.MinValue = -2147483648` or greater.
It is the same in any other language